# Conjunction vs. Implication in Coq

Tags: coq

I am currently working through the book [Software Foundations](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/). When theorems are defined, I often see chains of implications where I believe conjunctions would make more sense. For example, in defining the pigeonhole principle, the authors write:

```
Theorem pigeonhole_principle: ∀{X:Type} (l1 l2:list X),
  excluded_middle →
  (∀x, appears_in x l1 → appears_in x l2) →
  length l2 < length l1 →
  repeats l1.
```

This definition would make more sense to me if it looked more like this:

```
Theorem pigeonhole_principle: ∀{X:Type} (l1 l2:list X),
  (excluded_middle /\
  (∀x, appears_in x l1 → appears_in x l2) /\
  length l2 < length l1) →
  repeats l1.
```

Why is the first version correct? Why wouldn't conjunctions be more appropriate?

That is just an example. More generally, I am asking why conjunctions seem to be shunned in favor of chains of implications in coq.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the theorem-prover version of [function currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

To summarise, the two expressions are both correct (they are equivalent).

One says: Give me an “excluded middle”. Now give me hypothesis 2. Now give me hypothesis 3. Okay, here is a property “repeats l1”.

The other says: Give me an “excluded middle”, and hypothesis 2, and hypothesis 3. Okay, here is a property “repeats l1”.

Users and implementers of proof assistants such as Coq are also functional programmers and the curried version is as natural for them as the uncurried one.

Comment: I am familiar with currying, and thought that might be why. But how are they equivalent?

Comment: So, should I be interpreting the -> differently than the implication in propositional logic?

Comment: @mushroom Ah, this is the link you are looking for then: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry-Howard_correspondence (it's the same “Curry”, by the way). To paraphrase the Wikipedia page, you can imagine types as logical properties and expressions having these types as constructive witnesses.

Comment: @mushroom `->` is indeed implication. But a (constructive) proof of `A -> B` is also a way to transform any (constructive) proof of `A` into a (constructive) proof of `B`. So, very much like a function.

Comment: I guess what concerned me was that in regular propositional logic, (a & b) -> c would not be equivalent to (a -> b) -> c.  In the second case, as long as b were true then we could say that proposition c were true.  But the proof is curried, so it takes a single argument (evidence that a is true) and then returns a new proof that takes evidence that b is true and returns evidence that c is true.  The propositional logic issue I mentioned cannot occur because the arguments must be given one at a time in a particular order.  Am I on the right track?  Sorry for dragging this out.

Comment: In Coq (and most/all functional languages), `a -> b -> c` is interpreted as `a -> (b -> c)`, which is indeed equivalent to `(a & b) -> c`